# How to propagate changes made to one file to another file?

Tags: linux, files

I have some dotfiles that i want to save in GitHub so that i can edit and load them within my different workspaces ( office/home ). I don't want to copy the files every time i change them to the GitHub repository. I was thinking maybe i could have a counterpart of the file in the Git directory that got updated as soon as the original file changes. Practical example below.

Let's say i have a `~/.vimrc` (let's call it original file) file that i want to save (as a copy) in a git repository found in `~/workspace/dotfiles/`. Every time i edit the original file, i want its counterpart in `dotfiles` to be edited aswell.

How would i go about doing that?

I'm using ElementaryOS 0.4 ( built on Ubuntu 16.04 )

Comment: Use symbolic links to the git repository as your actual dotfiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [DopeGhoti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/20246/dopeghoti), you can do this using symlinks:

```
cd
mv .vimrc workspace/dotfiles/
ln -s workspace/dotfiles/.vimrc .
```

This generally works quite well.

There is a more sophisticated tool designed just for this though: [`vcsh`](https://github.com/RichiH/vcsh). This allows multiple repositories to be used, and more importantly, uses real files in `~` rather than symlinks:

```
vcsh init vim
vcsh vim add ~/.vimrc ~/.vim
vcsh vim commit -m 'Initial commit of my Vim configuration'
```

You can add `git` remotes, push, pull etc. [The documentation](https://github.com/RichiH/vcsh/tree/master/doc) goes into a lot more detail. `vcsh` is available as a package in many distributions.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I don't have a lot of .files, so i'll stick to the symlink alternative for now, but i'm starring vcsh's repository to use it once i have some more files